# Validating tickets by date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a ticket booking app for my sample project using Ruby on Rails 4.1. There are three models - Events, Tickets and Bookings. Events have many tickets and bookings. Tickets have many bookings and they belong to events. Bookings belongs to events and tickets.

In the Ticket model I use the following model to update the status of ticket bookings:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :bookings

  before_create :check_start_date
  before_update :check_start_date


    def check_start_date
        if (self.booking_start_date >= DateTime.now) && (self.booking_end_date != DateTime.now)
            self.status = 'Open'
        else
            self.status = 'Closed'
        end
    end

    def maximum_tickets_allowed
        (1..maximum_quantity.to_i).to_a
    end

end
```

The events show page lists the tickets and users can purchase tickets by clicking on the Buy Now button.

```
<% @event.tickets.each do |ticket| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Price</th>
                  <th>Quantity</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td><%= ticket.ticket_name %></td>
                  <td><%= number_to_currency(ticket.ticket_price) %></td>
                  <td><%= ticket.ticket_quantity %></td>
                  <td><%= ticket.status %></td>
                  <td><%= link_to "Buy Now", new_event_booking_path(@event, ticket_id: ticket.id), class: "btn btn-primary" %></td>
                  <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_event_ticket_path(@event, ticket), class: "btn btn-link" %></td>
                  <td><%= link_to "Delete", event_ticket_path(@event, ticket), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-link" %></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Visitors can buy tickets only from this events show page. Rest of the pages are locked down. How would I ensure that the user isn't allowed to buy tickets when the status is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`How would I ensure that the user isn't allowed to buy tickets when the status is closed?`

Looking at your Ticket model you already have the status field in your table so just check for it in your view and either don't show your link or you can simply disable it.

```
<% if ticket.status == "open" %>
  <td><%= link_to "Buy Now", new_event_booking_path(@event, ticket_id: ticket.id), class: "btn btn-primary" %></td>
<% end %>
```

**OR**

```
<td><%= link_to "Buy Now", new_event_booking_path(@event, ticket_id: ticket.id), class: "btn btn-primary", disabled: (ticket.status == "closed")  %></td>
```

**OR**

Use rails [`link_to_if`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_if) helper

```
<%= link_to_if ticket.status == "open", 'Buy Now', new_event_booking_path(@event, ticket_id: ticket.id), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```